# php 5.3 or below Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' help in fixing it

Tags: php, wamp

```
<?php

if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");

if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");

if (!isset($_GET["servername"])) $_GET["servername"] = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "select servername from server limit 1"))['servername'];

?>
```

Comment: if `mysqli_query` execution failed means it will return false .while `false['servername']` so think about it

Comment: @JYoThI it works perfectly on Xampp but not on wampp cause its less than php version 5.3 and i need to use it with that version

Comment: The  `x()['key']` syntax wont work in PHP 5.3. So you must either change the code, or upgrade the version of PHP you are using. Which do you want to do?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i know it doesnt work, i need a code compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue of course is the use of an array reference after the function calls.

So to amend the code so it will work on any version of PHP, try this

```
<?php

if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");

if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");

if (!isset($_GET["servername"])) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, "select servername from server limit 1"));
    $_GET["servername"] = $row['servername'];
}
?>
```